# How do I get host header when using h2c?

Tags: fastify

It looks like when I enable h2c in [fastify](/questions/tagged/fastify), then the host header never goes through. Instead I see headers such as:

```json
{
  ":method": "GET",
  ":scheme": "http",
  ":authority": "aimd.app",
  ":path": "/test-h2c",
  // ...
}
```

am I correct that `:authority` here is the same as `host`?

i.e. looks like I should update my library to resolve host as such:

```
url: () => new URL(req.url, `https://${req.headers.get(":authority") ?? req.headers.get("host") || ""}`),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of http2 pseudo-headers :authority & :method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502726/what-is-the-purpose-of-http2-pseudo-headers-authority-method)